# Can Mono's CSharpRepl be used to create methods and classes?

Tags: c#, mono, read-eval-print-loop

If I type the following:

```
class Klass {
public int X;
}
```

I get the error:

{interactive}(1,1): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol 'class', expecting 'using'

Is there a way to input classes and methods into Mono's CSharpRepl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `csharp` command packaged with mono 2.10.x does not support class declarations. You will have to upgrade to mono 3.0.x for that.